AWS Elasticache timeout error even with good configuration
The backend of my application is hosted with Elastic Beanstalk, everything works great. I recently decided to configure a cache by creating an ElastiCache (Redis) cluster and I have a big problem around a timeout error. Basically, with each request I make to the backend that goes through the cache, it hangs in the void with no response from the backend, until a timeout error occurs after about thirty seconds.
Here is a simple example of a route that crashes with this timeout:
app.get('/test-redis', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      await redisClient.set('test', 'value');
      const value = await redisClient.get('test');
      res.json({ value });
  } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error interacting with Redis:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Error interacting with Redis');
  }
});

and here is the Redis configuration for elasticache:
require('dotenv').config();
const Redis = require('ioredis');

const redisClusterEndpoints = [
  { host: '<cluster node 1>', port: 6379 },
  { host: '<cluster node 2>', port: 6379 },
  { host: '<cluster node 3>', port: 6379 },
];

const client = new Redis.Cluster(redisClusterEndpoints, {
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
  },
  redisOptions: {
    connectTimeout: 10000,
  },
  retryDelayOnFailover: 1000,
  retryDelayOnClusterDown: 1000,
  maxRetriesPerRequest: 5,
  scaleReads: 'slave',
});

client.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Redis error:', error);
});

client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Redis connection closed');
});

client.on('reconnecting', (delay) => {
  console.log(`Redis reconnecting in ${delay} ms`);
});

module.exports = client;


I have already checked a lot of time my AWS configurations (VPC, Security groups, NAT gateways, subnets...) and it seems good.
Has anyone ever had this kind of problem? Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Same problem. No solution I'm connecting from an EC2 instance. Did you find anything?

In my case it was that I was not enabling TLS on the redis client..

@Joan just watned to say THANK YOU.
Several hours of work, endless diagnostics with chatgpt walking me through so many AWS settings, checking and rechecking security groups... your one comment on this answer saved me and all works well now... I really REALLY appreciate you taking the time to come back here and mention your fix
